# Android SonarQube Integration Error: Error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, sonarqube

Here is the gradle settings  showing the sonarqube properties. version is 2.7. the error is thrown after running gradlew sonarqube command

```
           sonarqube {
           properties {
                property "sonar.projectName", "com.app.clim"
                property "sonar.projectKey", "com.app.clim"
                property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
                property "sonar.profile", "Android Lint"
                property "sonar.sources", "./src/main/java"
                property "sonar.exclusions", "build/**,**/*.png"
                property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true
                property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/slf/lint-results.xml"
             }
           }
```

Comment: were you able to find the solution?